# Eclipse RCP - Support for external plugins (without adding dependencies in main application)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies, external, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP Application with a bunch of plugins. I need to distribute it and let people make plugins for it.

Currently, I create new plugin projects with fragments that are integrated into the main application by adding them to the dependencies list of the main application's product file.

What should I do to make the application load plugins which are developed separately?

Thanks

Comment: If you include the 'p2' installation manager plugins in your RCP you can use all the usual 'Install New Software' menus.

Comment: Is it possible to export a plugin as a jar file, copy it to the plugins folder and update the config.ini file to include this jar? I'm able to separately export a plugin like this (which was already in the dependencies list of the RCP application). Will the RCP application update its dependencies based on the config.ini file?